# Saving a dictionary to a file, with user input

Tags: python, file

I am creating an Address book, where you can Add/update, search, display the address, and delete addresses. I am trying to save the dict to a file.

I have tried writing to the file, but every time the program resets, the file does too.

```py
addressbook = {}
while(True):

    print('ADDRESS BOOK')
    print('-----------------------')
    print('-----------------------')
    print('1 - Add/Update contact')
    print('2 - Display all contacts')
    print('3 - Search')
    print('4 - Delete contact')
    print('5 - Quit')
    choice = input('')

    if choice == ('1'):
        addupdate = input('Do you want to add(1) or update(2) a contact?')
        if addupdate == ('1'):
            name = input('Enter the persons name:')
            address = input('Enter the address:')
            addressbook[name] = address
            print('Name added')
        elif addupdate == ('2'):
            thechange = input('''Who's address do you want to change?:''')
            newaddress = input('''What is the new address?:''')
            for key, value in addressbook.items():
                if key == thechange:
                    del addressbook[key]
                    addressbook[thechange] = newaddress
                    print('Address updated')
                    break

    elif choice == ('2'):
        for key, value in addressbook.items():
            print('Name:' + key)
            print('Address:' + value)
            print('--------')
    elif choice == ('3'):
        search_name = input('''Who's name do you want to search?:''')
        position = 0
        for key, value in addressbook.items():
            position = position + 1
            if key == search_name:
                print('Name %s found in %s position' % (search_name, position))
                break
            else:
                print('Name %s not found in %s position' %
                      (search_name, position))
    elif choice == ('4'):
        which_one = input('''Who's address do you want to delete?:''')
        for key, value in addressbook.items():
            if key == which_one:
                del addressbook[key]
                print('%s deleted' % which_one)
                break
            else:
                print('Name not found')
    elif choice == ('5'):
        addressfile = open('/home/robert/Addressbook.txt', 'w')
        addressfile.write(str(addressbook))
        addressfile.close
        break
addressfile = open('/home/robert/Addressbook.txt')
addressname = str(addressfile.read())
```

The file saves the dict, but if you start the program again, the file resets.

Comment: using ```open(file, 'w')``` writes to the file from scratch. You should either append to the file with ```open(file, 'a')```, or read the file to a variable, edit the variable, then save it to the file again.

Comment: Thanks, but when I run the program and display, nothing shows up. If I add something, it will show up.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems. First, you're using code `w`, which means to overwrite, when you want ot be using `a`, which means to append:

```
addressfile = open('/home/robert/Addressbook.txt', 'a')
```

Second, you're not closing the file. You're invoking the `addressfile.close` function, but you're not *calling* it - therefore, the file never gets saved, which is why nothing is showing up after you're running it. Do this:

```
addressfile.close()
```

or, if you don't want to have to deal with closing the file, you can use `with`, which does it automatically when you go out of the `with` block:

```
elif choice == '5':
    with open('/home/robert/Addressbook.txt', 'a') as addressfile:
        addressfile.write(str(addressbook))
    break
```

Comment: Great answer, also i suggest you also read ```addressbook``` from the file instead of declaring it as an empty dict( which allows checking for duplicate members in the dict ).